# How to read a tuple?

Tags: c++, tuples

Code is below. Seems simple, but get some compilation errors that I cannot find the bug.

```
#define ENABLE_IF(Condition, Type) typename enable_if < (Condition), Type>::type

template<size_t I = 0, class... Ts>
ENABLE_IF(I == sizeof...(Ts), void) read(QDataStream& in, tuple<Ts...>& t)
{}

template<size_t I = 0, class... Ts>
ENABLE_IF(I < sizeof...(Ts), void)  read(QDataStream& in, tuple<Ts...>& t)
{
   in >> std::get<I>(t);
   read<I + 1>(in, t);
}
```

Error for the lat statement: `error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'enable_if<I<0x01,void>::type read(QDataStream &,std::tuple<_Types1...> &)'`

After more testing, it turns out the following code is okay

```
template<size_t I = 0, class Tuple>
ENABLE_IF(I == tuple_size<Tuple>::value, void) read(QDataStream& in, Tuple& t)
{}

template<size_t I = 0, class Tuple>
ENABLE_IF(I < tuple_size<Tuple>::value, void)  read(QDataStream& in, Tuple& t)
{
    in >> std::get<I>(t);
    read<I + 1>(in, t);
}
```

This uses the tuple type as a template parameter other than its element type pack. What is the reason? A compilation bug for VS2013?

Tested with other compilers. The original code is okay. I think it is a VS2013 bug. :-(

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2263940cafa8b56d). Post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Jefffrey and where is your template instantiation ?

Comment: at age 42 you're allowed to reproduce (but it's discouraged in females)

Comment: @sehe I'm not 42 yet, but the joke applies either way :).

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple! Your primary template has no only one parameter. You simply should pass second argument Ts...:

```
read<I + 1, Ts...>(in, t);
```

And reverse order reading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <tuple>

template<size_t I, typename... Ts>
struct reader
{
    static void read(std::istream& i, std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
    {
        i >> std::get<I>(t);
        reader<I - 1, Ts...>::read(i, t);
    }
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct reader<0, Ts...>
{
    static void read(std::istream& i, std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
    {
        i >> std::get<0>(t);
    }
};

template<typename... Ts>
void read(std::istream& i, std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
{
    reader<sizeof...(Ts) - 1, Ts...>::read(i, t);
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream istr("1 2");
    std::tuple<int, double> t;
    read(istr, t);
}
```

Comment: **Note:** The above snippet is somewhat inaccurate (unless OP wants this behavior); it will read the elements in the wrong order. `2` will be in the 1st element of `t`, and `1` will be in the second.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp Yes, I told how to fix the code in the example and just paste a "reverse" reading. And i wrote about this.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this too, so I wrote this (C++17 only due to `if constexpr`):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<class Head, class... Tail>
std::tuple<Head, Tail...> tuple_read_impl(std::istream& is) {
    Head val;
    is >> val;
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Tail) == 0) // this was the last tuple value
        return std::tuple{val};
    else
        return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple{val}, tuple_read_impl<Tail...>(is));
}

template<class... Types>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::tuple<Types...> &tup) {
    tup = tuple_read_impl<Types...>(is);
    return is;
}

int main ()
{
    std::tuple<size_t, size_t> tup;
    std::cin >> tup;
    auto [x, y] = tup;
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y;
}
```